# how to do searching this argument [] on kibana or elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I set up elk(Elasticsearch kibana logstash). And I want to search this argument  [] on kibana or elasticsearch. ( the argument is [] )

How can ı do  it ( [] )?

Comment: You can please elaborate more. A sample document with expected response will help

Comment: I want to search the square brackets [] in elasticsearch. I write this, but despite the data, the answer is blank.
{
   "query": {
     "match": {
       "syslog_category_id": {
         "query": "[]",
         "type": "phrase"
       }
     }
   }
}                                 
I'm thinking that elasticsearch doesn't care that [] like a character
How can I solve this?

Comment: in elastic, every field values is a multi valued field internally. And elastic does not store empty array for a field. Any field added to a document is stored under special field named "_source" and which can be retrieved.  And each field is indexed if it has value, which later can be "searched" upon. Here elastic will not store as [], but will rather store nothing against that corresponding field. So you cannot search by empty array. 

P.S. You can search for missing value using "exists"